# C - Setting a struct to null (incompatible types in assignment)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null

I have the following struct:

```
struct elem {
  int number;
  char character;
};

struct item {
  struct elem element;
};
```

and the following function:

```
void init(struct item *wrapper) {
  assert(wrapper != NULL);
  wrapper->element = NULL;
}
```

`item->element = NULL` yields a `incompatible types in assignment`. Why is that? Shouldn't setting a struct to NULL be okay?

Comment: Only pointers can be set to `NULL`. You're trying to null an object.

Comment: Maybe you want to `memset` it to 0 instead ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C `NULL` is generally defined as the following

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

This means that it's a pointer value.  In this case your attempting to assign a pointer (`NULL`) to a non-pointer value `item::element` and getting the appropriate message.  It seems like your intent is to have `element` be a pointer here so try the following

```
struct item {
  struct elem* element;
};
```

Comment: Regarding `main`, I am not using it. I just didnt know what to name the struct for the question here. I'll rename it here though.

Comment: But `init` takes a pointer. `wrapper` is a pointer to that struct so I should be able to set it to NULL using `->`. No?

Comment: @Darksky even though you have a pointer to `main` the `element` field inside of `main` is still a non-pointer type.

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` is a pointer value, `wrapper->element` is not a pointer, therefore you cannot assign it `NULL`

Comment: But `init` takes a pointer. `wrapper` is a pointer to that struct so I should be able to set it to NULL using `->`. No?

Comment: @Darksky the outer object is a pointer, but the struct's member object is not a pointer.  Regardless if the `wrapper` object is a  pointer, passed by value, or (in C++ case) a reference, it does not change the members' types to match

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answers, sometimes it makes sense to create a NULL struct.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 2):

1. element is not a pointer and hence cannot be assigned NULL.
2. `main->element` is wrong usage. You cannot access a structure's element using it's name. It should be `wrapper->element`. You should access it using the variable name.

Comment: +1 for catching an important flaw. It shouldn't be `main`, but `wrapper`.

Comment: 2. That was a typo. Obviously.. Otherwise the error would be different.